# enhance code running timing in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time

I am trying to speed up my code by running it on highly performance computer, and anaconda as well, could anyone provide any suggestion, given that the workbook size sheets are 600 sheets. 
the following is my code

```
#gc.collect()
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

file = r'C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\stations\\9575_output.xlsx'
list_dfs = []

xls = xlrd.open_workbook(file, on_demand=True)
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names():
    df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name)

    list_dfs.append(df)

dfs = pd.concat(list_dfs,axis=0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\stations\\9575_output_Concat.xlsx')
dfs.to_excel(writer,'9575Contatenated')
writer.save()
```

Given that I got the result after 8 hours of running the code.

Comment: my workbook file size consists of 600 sheets that mean I am gonna split each file to 600 files then merge the 600 CSV files would it be possible ??!!

Comment: the status that the 600 files will be read and written so it is a lot of time.

Comment: and Regarding who said it is duplicated i tried the code without success. it gives me empty file all the time.

Comment: Don't use pandas for this. It isn't made for such loads and adds a huge overhead. You could try PyTables if you like the pandas like handling.